# Determine If Iframe Is In Secure Origin To Allow "Powerful Features"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, fullscreen

Based on the changes to Chrome outlined in [Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins), is there a way to detect if an `<iframe>` is included under an insecure origin?

I'm working on a video player that can be embedded, and want to be able to use the Fullscreen API. Right now, going fullscreen logs a warning in the console, but I'd like to be able to remove the button if the player is embedded in a site served over `HTTP` to avoid future compatibility issues.

I'd prefer to hide the button immediately, instead of waiting for the user to click it, detect that it's not allowed, and then hide it, if that is possible.

Comment: I don't know a good way (or even if there's a way) to achieve what u looking for. I feel like it's difficult to make it futures especially it all depends on the browser. Right now we can use fullscreenEnabled to check whether the document allows it, I hope they keep this interface after that change

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the iframe's code: `alert(document.referrer);` It should show the url of the parent you can use to check for https.